# Does Key order matter in a MongoDB BSON doc?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I know certain commends need the hashmap / dictionary to be ordered, but does the actual BSON document in MongoDB matter and would the index still work?

E.g.

```
db.people.ensureIndex({LName:1, FName:1});
```

Would it work on both:

```
{LName:"abc", FName:"def"}, 
{FName:"ghi", LName:"jkl"}
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of a document's properties does not affect indexing.

You can see this for yourself by running this query:

```
db.people.find({LName: "abc"}).explain()
```

and then this query:

```
db.people.find({LName: "jkl"}).explain()
```

you should see that MongoDB will use the index in both cases (the `cursor` property should be something like `"BtreeCursor LName_1_FName_1"`).