# Mongoid Hash type became BSON::Document after a find

Tags: hash, mongoid, document, bson

I am using mongoid 6.0.3

```
class C
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :h, type: Hash, default: {}
end

c = C.new
c.h = {"a" => "b"}
c.save!
puts c.h.class       # gives Hash
saved_c = C.find(c.id)
puts saved_c.h.class # gives BSON::Document
```

Did I miss something ? I cannot figure out why the hash become a BSON::Document after a simple find ?

Answer (score 0):

BSON uses ordered keys in BSON::Documents and within the mongo database.

```
 {"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}
```

and

```
 {"c" => "d", "a" => "b"}
```

is the "same" hash to ruby.

Mongo/BSON spec says those two documents are NOT the same, because the keys are ordered differently.

To you (the user) it might not matter what the key order is. But if you did care, BSON and MongoDB will respect that for you.

[Does Key order matter in a MongoDB BSON doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453424/does-key-order-matter-in-a-mongodb-bson-doc)